# C : confusion over a small piece of code - what is '&0x'?

Tags: c, variables, hex

I'm new to C, and I am trying to workout two things in this peace of code;

- What is the purpose of &0xfe and &0x01 below?
- __u16 obviously this is a variable but what type and what are they called?

Thanks in advance!

```
static __u16 smile_bmp[] = {0x3C, 0x42, 0x95, 0xA1, 0xA1, 0x95, 0x42, 0x3C};

displayImage(smile_bmp,res, daddress, file);

int displayImage(__u16 bmp[], int res, int daddress, int file)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
         block[i] = (bmp[i]&0xfe) >>1 | (bmp[i]&0x01) << 7;
        }
    res = i2c_smbus_write_i2c_block_data(file, daddress, 16,
        (__u8 *)block);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: `__u16` is not a variable, it's a type (defined in `<asm-generic/types.h>` if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression: `(bmp[i]&0xfe) >>1 | (bmp[i]&0x01) << 7` as a whole is really a rotation (aka circular shift) of the 8 least significant bits of `bmp[i]`.

The `bmp[i] & 0xfe` part is taking the number in `bmp[i]` and masking off the lower bit (`0xfe` means "FE in hexadecimal", which translates to `11111110` in binary), so when you `and` the two together, it's setting the lowest bit to 0 without changing any of the others (well, any of the others among the 8 least significant -- given the `bmp[i]` is of type `__u16`, it apparently has 16 bits, so the upper 8 bits in the mask are also zeros, so they're set to zero in the result as well).

Likewise, the `bmp[i] & 0x01` part is masking off all *but* the lowest bit. 0x01 is 00000001, so when you `and` this value with anything else, you retain the original value of the least significant bit, and set all the other bits to 0.

It's then shifting the first to the right one bit, and the second to the left by 7 bits, and then using a bitwise `or` to put the two pieces back together. The net result is that what started out as bit 0 is now bit 7, and all of the others are shifted to the right one place (the previous bit 7 is now bit 6, previous bit 6 is now bit 5, etc.)

As an aside, the names `__u8` and `__u16` are reserved for the implementation, so unless those are actually provided by the implementation, you have undefined behavior (i.e., you're not allowed to define those names in your code).

Comment: thank you.  I now understand circular rotation and bit wise operators, which makes that peace of code look simple now.
__u8 and __16 are still not clear. When would I use __16 instead of an unsigned Int?

Comment: @Mwilliams03: The obvious reason would be if you want to assure that the type is always exactly 16 bits, where `int` could be anything from 16 on up. The standard way to do this would be to `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint16_t` as the type.

Answer (score 5):

Its a [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) AND of the variable (`bmp[i]`) on the left and a constant expressed as [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)